# File too big for lambda tmp folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

**What i try to accomplish:**
Hey guys,
i created a lambda function, which downloads a mp4 file of s3 and then cuts the last 30 seconds of it and uploads it to the desired folder on the s3 again. I use the fs module of nodejs for writing and reading the file. After writing the buffer to the lambda /tmp folder, i cut it with ffmpeg, then reading the buffer of the newly created file and uploading it to s3 again.

**The problem:**
The mp4 files can get to almost 1gb. AWS lambda is only providing 500MB of disk space on the tmp folder. Thats why the function gets cancled, as soon as the file is bigger than allowed.

**What i tried:**
I tried to cut the buffer with a simple splice method. I tried to start the `fs.createWriteStream function` at the half, but then the file was always corrupted.

Is there a way to solve that problem? I will always need the last 30 seconds of every mp4 file, which gets uploaded to S3. No matter how big the file is.

Theres some code how i do it:

Writing the file, cause otherwise i could not use ffmpeg on it.

```
await fs.writeFile('/tmp/tempFile.mp4', origiVideo.Body, (err) => {
   if (err) {
      console.log('Writefile Error!');
      throw err;
   }
});
```

```
ffmpeg()
   .input('/tmp/tempFile.mp4')
   .inputOptions(['-ss ' + finalTime])
   .outputOptions(['-t ' + finalDuration])
   .noAudio()
   .output('/tmp/output.mp4')
   .on('end', () => {
       console.log('FFMPEG Done!');
       resolve();
   })
   .on('error', (err) => {
       console.log('Error: \n' + err);
       return reject(new Error(err))
   })
                    .run();
```

Reading the file to reupload it so s3.

```
const uploadBuffer = await fs.readFile('/tmp/output.mp4', (err, data) => {
   if(err) throw err;
});
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Isn't this a good usecase for an EFS share? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

Comment: Thanks @b0tting. I will have a look into that :)